# Spades used in pressure testing PE Pipe lines

Tags: gas

As we all know the industry is heading into PE pipelines in the gathering fields fast. Some applications use DN560-DN1000, and the spades is very heavy and in awkward positions. Is there PE spades/blanks in the market to ease the manual handling?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what this question is asking. Perhaps a bit more clarity and a bit fewer acronyms?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't take shopping requests